# Что значит "Python не является автономным инструментом"?

Tags: python, терминология, интеграция

Что значит "Python не является автономным инструментом"? Значит, что он связан с другими языками? Может, что в нем можно использовать библиотеки с других языков?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Лучше спрашивать у автора этого изречения. Возможно, имелось в виду то, что python-скрипты нельзя просто перенести на другой компьютер, если там не установлен интерпретатор и библиотеки. Но это только моя догадка - без контекста эта фраза звучит не очень осмысленно.

Comment: Включим "догадку" :) Для запуска скрипта нужен установленный на компе python,  причем нужной версии... Ну при этом есть обходные решения (например, pyinstaller), созается специальный exe, в котором упакован и скрипт, и инерпретатор, и нужные библиотеки. Правда, скрипт типа HelloWorld.exe получается на 6 мегабайт, но при нанешних сетях и флешках это не особо страшно...